# Why is this script causing this error when trying to link to a different page with React router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have this scroll script running on my Home page's componentDidMount and when I try to link my new page using React router I get this error:

*Home.js:41 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null
    at eval (Home.js:41)*

Here is the Home page code with componentDidMount script and the Link:

```
class Home extends Component{
    componentDidMount(){
        window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
            let parent = document.getElementById('parallax-container');
            let children = parent.getElementsByTagName('div');
            let cover = document.getElementById('cover');
            for(let i = 0; i < children.length; i++){
                children[i].style.transform = 'translateY(' + (window.pageYOffset * i / children.length) + 'px)';
            }
            cover.style.height = (window.pageYOffset)*0.8 + "px";

        }, false)
    }
    render(){

        return(
            <>
            <div className={classes.Hero}>
                <div id="cover" className={classes.BlackCover} ></div>
                <div id='parallax-container'>
                    <Drip color='Black'/>
                    <Drip color='Yellow'/>
                    <Drip color='Pink'/>
                    <Drip color='Blue'/>
                </div>
                <div id="intro" className={classes.Intro}>
                    <div id="avatar" className="ch-item ch-img-1">              
                        <div className="ch-info-wrap">
                            <div className="ch-info">
                                <div className="ch-info-front ch-img-1"></div>
                                <div className="ch-info-back"></div>    
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <Link to={'/winner'}><button>Let's Chat!</button></Link>
            </div>
            </>
        );
    }
}            

export default Home;
```

And here is the Switch for the Router:

```
render(){
      return(
      <main>
          <Switch>
              <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
             <Route exact path='/winner' component={Winner}/>
         </Switch>
     </main>
     );
}
```

And here is the page I am trying to link to:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Winner extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>Winner!</div>
        );
    }
}
export default Winner;
```

The error is saying it is getting stuck on the *let children = parent.getElementsByTagName('div'); * line. I haven't used Routing before so I'm guessing this is just some dumb mistake but I don't know what to do to fix it.

Comment: can you please share a minimal working example like a codesandbox? It's mucht easier to help then :)

Comment: Routing seems good. May be other thing is causing this problem. However, It is difficult to be sure until the codes are more visible.

Comment: error says "parent" is null, so it might not be rendered

Comment: try using a remove event listener for your home component in the `componentWillUnmount` lifecycle method. You can see how to do it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38564080/remove-event-listener-on-unmount-react

Comment: And there are chances that the callback is called before the `componentWillUnmount` called but the `parallax-container` element has gone. Therefore, try to return early if parent is not exist. use something like `if(!parent)return`

Comment: @kkesley you were right I needed to unmount the listener. Thank you!! if you want to post that as an answer I can mark it correct for you. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it throws an error is because the listener is still active when you're moving to the new page. And when it's fired, there are no more `parallax-container` element as it only exists in the `Home` page.

Try removing the listener in `componentWillUnmount`. A good example is from this answer: [Remove Event Listener On Unmount React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38564080/remove-event-listener-on-unmount-react)

or here's the answer from that link:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.onScroll = this.onScroll.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll, false);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll, false);
}
```

Another note is to always check whether the element exist as it's possible than the listener is still active but the element is not rendered. A simple check should do:

```
if(!parent){return}
```

Comment: Thanks again for the help!