# how to remove event listener from document in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a beginner in React and I have some problems. I want to add some event listeners in `componentDidMount()` method, plus I need to catch the event to find which key was clicked.
And I want to remove it in `componentWillUnmount()` method. I did it on with extra function. But there is some issue. After some time passes (for example after one second) I want to update state in parent component(which triggers component unmounting and I did it), but there is One problem I cant remove event listener in `componentWillUnmount()` so please help me.

here is my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class Element extends Component {

    componentDidMount(){
        const {attributes, startTime, timeOut, automaticAnswer} ={...this.props};
            document.addEventListener('keypress', function func(e){
                that.handleClick(e, startTime, attributes.keyBoardKey, false, timeOut, func)});
    }


    handleClick(event, startTime, realAnswer, automaticAnswer, timeOut, func){
        this.props.fillAnswer(event.key ? event.key : '', startTime, realAnswer, automaticAnswer, timeOut);
        document.removeEventListener('keypress', func);
    }

    render() {
        const {attributes, startTime, timeOut, automaticAnswer} ={...this.props};
        if(automaticAnswer ){
            this.handleClick('', startTime, attributes.keyBoardKey, true, timeOut);
        }


        return (
            <span className={attributes.className}>{attributes.value}</span>
        );
    }
}

export default Element;
```

Comment: Hello, Can you please describe which functionality you need to perform actually?

Comment: It's a test. Some word appear on screen written with different colors. User must press on the correct key(it'w written in description). User has 1 second to answer the question. After one second another component must appear and it shows how may of your answers was correct. Then user click "next" button and another word appears... And again and Again

Comment: Did you tried to get any other event?

Comment: which event for example? I need keydown event

Comment: There are mainly 3 events of the keyboard: keydown,  keypress ,keyup.
You can use anyone of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below link will match ur usecase hopefully,also i guess ur qestion duplicate question
[This how you do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38564080/remove-event-listener-on-unmount-react/38564123)

```
constructor(props){
super(props);
this.onScroll = this.onScroll.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {
window.addEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll, false);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll, false);
}
```

Comment: I saw that. But my problem is that I can't get event in my function like that

Comment: any error in specific,like ur getting problem with the "this" keyword

Comment: I had very silly mistake. Thanks man!!!

Comment: your reply helped me a lot