# Remove onclick react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a div with onClick event. At a certain moment of the application I would like to remove that event. How can i do it?
I tried with:

```
document.removeEventListener('click', this.function)
document.removeEventListener('mousedown', this.function)
```

Comment: We can do a much better job of helping you if you provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove Event Listener On Unmount React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38564080/remove-event-listener-on-unmount-react)

Comment: @rdarioduarte - The question's fairly unclear, but I'm not getting the impression they're talking about a DOM element they're handling events on directly.

Comment: Why are you registering an event listener in react? React provides this functionality out of the box.

Comment: @Kobe - It's not clear that the OP *is* registering the handler directly.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, the question is very unclear.

Comment: @Chris, can you provide additional code where you add the event listener?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a **very** active place. When you post a question (or answer!), please *stick around* so you can respond to anything that comes up in the comments.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder as you said it is very unclear, but I believe it could lead him to the right direction

Answer (score 1):

I assume the div is set up with a click handler in your React code, not directly via `addEventListener`. That's why you can't remove it with `removeEventListener`; that's now how React works.

You have at least two options:

1. Make the component that renders the `div` stateful, and use the state to either have an `onClick` or not when you render the `div`.
2. Make the component that renders the `div` stateful, and always have the handler, but only actually do something in it depending on state.

#2 is fairly simple: Within your handler, you check state to see whether you should do something.

There's a bit more to #1, so here's an example of #1 where a tickbox controls whether the `div` has an `onClick` (using hooks):

```js
const {useState, useCallback} = React;

function Example() {
    const [flag, setFlag] = useState(true);
    
    const onFlagChange = useCallback(e => {
        setFlag(e.target.checked);
    }, []);
    
    const handleClick = useCallback(e => {
        console.log(`div clicked at ${new Date().toISOString()}`);
    }, []);
    
    return (
        <div>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" onChange={onFlagChange} checked={flag} />
                Handler enabled
            </label>
            <div onClick={flag ? handleClick : null}>Click here to see if handler fires</div>
      </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Example />,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.10.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.10.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Here's a class-based version of that:

```js
const {Component} = React;

class Example extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {flag: true};
        this.onFlagChange = this.onFlagChange.bind(this);
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    onFlagChange(e) {
        this.setState({flag: e.target.checked});
    }
    
    handleClick() {
        console.log(`div clicked at ${new Date().toISOString()}`);
    }
    
    render() {
        const {onFlagChange, handleClick} = this;
        const {flag} = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" onChange={onFlagChange} checked={flag} />
                    Handler enabled
                </label>
                <div onClick={flag ? handleClick : null}>Click here to see if handler fires</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Example />,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.10.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.10.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

try to remove listener directly from your div.

```
const your_div = document.getElementById('your_div_id');
your_div.removeEventListener('click', this.function)
```

Comment: why minus? i understand good practices in react but see that this guy already has implemented listener by `addEventListener` function, and we don't know how big this functionality is. Refactoring into `good practices` is not always best approach, especially in big projects.

Comment: FWIW, there's nothing in the question saying that the OP has used `addEventListener`.